# Changing MainForm at runtime

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010

How can I change MainForm of my application at runtime ?

Comment: Why do you need to change it?

Comment: Because I'm calling another FormAuthorize Form on OnShow() event of my MainForm. It has two buttons and one of them is Exit. Clicking on exit should terminate the application without appearing and disappearing of the MainForm. Though I'd made my MainForm visibility to false on OnShow event when the form gets fired but I can't control the visibility of MainForm on show event

Comment: You don't need to change the MainForm to accomplish that. There are better alternatives: 1) create (via `new`) and show FormAuthorize before creating the MainForm. If Exit is pressed, don't create the MainForm at all. 2) if you must create the MainForm first, then you can call `Application->Terminate()` if Exit is pressed, and use `Application->ShowMainForm=false` to keep the MainForm hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Once the `MainForm` has been established by the first call to `TApplication::CreateForm()`, it cannot be changed afterwards.  You can either write code to control which `TForm` class gets passed to the first call to `CreateForm()`, or you can use a hidden `TForm` as the `MainForm` and then have it display secondary forms as needed.